# django annotate instance not working

Tags: django

I have model ModelA

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
    #other fields


class Friend(models.Model):
   user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
   name = charfield

class Enemy(models.Model):
   user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I want to filter friend's name from ModelA, so:

```
ModelA.objects.annotate(friend=Friend.objects.get(user_id=user_id)).filter(friend__name='abc')
```

Here, annotating friend is not working but above line says my requirement.  I want all records of ModelA whose friend's name is 'abc'. How ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks a bit of a mess, you are creating all this models for a single type, user_id is not needed like that user would be fine, you should provide related names to be able to understand what you are trying to query (although again...you are not DRYing yourself), annotate is used for Aggregation and not what you are trying to do, if you want to present a new value you should be using extra, apart from that if your example was clear and properly structured you wouldn't even need extra() on your query.

Answer (score 0):

Using `annotate()` is completely unnecessary.  `annotate()` is used for things like appending a aggregation to a model (such as the Count() of a user's friend_set).  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregating-annotations

So, let's start at the beginning..

Why are your foreign keys named "user_id"?  When using the ORM, Friend.user_id is going to return a **User** object, and not just the user's integer primary key.  The name of your property in ModelA and Friend should reflect this.  **Change 'user_id' to 'user'**.

So, here's how I would define those models:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Friend(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Enemy(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Next, you would find all the instances of `ModelA` that are related to a `User` that in turn, has a `Friend` named 'abc', like so:

```
results = ModelA.objects.filter(user__friend__name='abc')
```

**NOTE:  There are two underscores (_) between the tokens user, friend, and name.**

I would highly recommend that you spend a lot more time reading through the documentation for Django's ORM here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/